# Forest's \Forest* macro: how can nodes be used outside the tree?

Tags: forest

This question is about a particular feature of the [forest package](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest).

According to the manual (22):

> ```
> \begin{forest}<tree>\end{forest} 
> \Forest[*]{<tree>}
> ```
>
> The environment and the starless version of the macro introduce a group; the starred macro does not, so the created nodes can be used afterwards. (Note that this will leave a lot of temporary macros lying around. This shouldn’t be a problem, however, since all of them reside in the `\forest` namespace.)

By default nodes in the tree get a name of the form `node@id`. However, if you use `name=<name>` then a node is instead named `<name>`.

Given this, my possibly naïve understanding of this feature suggested that something like one of the variations in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
  \Forest*{
    [A, name=a
      [B, name=b]
      [C, name=c]
    ]
  }
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw [red] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a);
  \tikz[overlay]\draw [blue] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a);
  \tikz[remember picture]\draw [green] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a);
  \tikz\draw [magenta] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a);
\end{document}
```

might produce something roughly similar to this:

[image: triangle ABC with overlaid red connections]

However, I cannot figure out how to get anything like this, although the nodes are, indeed, accessible outside the tree in the sense that I do not get errors and, moreover, some of the above variants draw something which looks roughly isomorphic to my target image:

[image: isomorphic-ish connecting lines in magenta, green and blue]

Note that I would also expect, as implied above, to get errors if I tried to reference a node created within an ordinary `forest` environment, after that environment ended. But, in fact, I get just the same behaviour in this case - and with the unstarred `\Forest` - as with `\Forest*`. That is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
  \Forest{
    [A, name=a1
      [B, name=b1]
      [C, name=c1]
    ]
  }
  \Forest*{
    [A, name=a
      [B, name=b]
      [C, name=c]
    ]
  }
  \begin{forest}
    [A, name=a2
      [B, name=b2]
      [C, name=c2]
    ]
  \end{forest}
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw [red] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a);
  \tikz[overlay]\draw [blue] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a);
  \tikz[remember picture]\draw [green] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a);
  \tikz\draw [magenta] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a);
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw [red] (a1) -- (b1) -- (c1) -- (a1);
  \tikz[overlay]\draw [blue] (a1) -- (b1) -- (c1) -- (a1);
  \tikz[remember picture]\draw [green] (a1) -- (b1) -- (c1) -- (a1);
  \tikz\draw [magenta] (a1) -- (b1) -- (c1) -- (a1);
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw [red] (a2) -- (b2) -- (c2) -- (a2);
  \tikz[overlay]\draw [blue] (a2) -- (b2) -- (c2) -- (a2);
  \tikz[remember picture]\draw [green] (a2) -- (b2) -- (c2) -- (a2);
  \tikz\draw [magenta] (a2) -- (b2) -- (c2) -- (a2);
\end{document}
```

produces the following without error:

[image: isomorphic variations with different environments and macros]

A two-part question: ;)

- How should this feature be used?
- What exactly is its intended purpose, if not the one suggested by my (possibly idiosyncratic) reading of the manual?

Note that I can perfectly easily produce the target image in other, more convenient ways. It is just an example to illustrate how I expected the feature to be used.

*The following is not part of the question. It is an attempt to forestall further answers which treat the question as a 'how do I draw this?' rather than a 'what is this meant to be for and how am I meant to use it?'*

Just for the record:

```
\Forest{[A[B][C, tikz={\draw [red] () -- (!s) -- (!u) -- ();}]]}
```

will produce a tree which looks just like the target i.e. in which the tree branches are darker because the red overlays the black, while:

```
\Forest{for tree={edge={draw=red}}[A[B][C, tikz={\draw [red] () -- (!s);}]]}
```

will produce a version which is not like the target image because the red lines are evenly coloured, but which would probably be what I actually wanted if this were a question about how to draw the target image, which it is not.

Comment: Why do you read packages documentation? That's just looking for trouble ;)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Certainly it finds trouble often enough... ;). I was wondering if there was a way of using this to work around the problems caused by combining `tikzmark`, `forest` and XeLaTeX, raised in another question somebody asked.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I guess that means you don't know the answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I can't produce any different behaviour at all. Even if I reference nodes named in the regular environment, I don't get errors and I still get these shifted tree skeletons.

Comment: Yes. I did some experiments and got similar results. Hopefully Sašo will shed some light here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nodes remaining in memory `\Forest*` because introduces no group are not tikz's nodes, but forest's *logical* nodes, i.e. the node hierarchy.

The intended use of this feature is to be able to build a tree in several places in the document, or to reuse trees, like below. (I will include this example in the documentation.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\Forest*{
  [VP,name=VP
    [V]
    [DP]
  ]
}
\forestset{for name={VP}{for tree={s=0}}}% workaround for the bug
\Forest*{
  [TP
    [T]
    [,replace by=VP]
  ]
}
\end{document}
```

[image: reusing a tree]

(While constructing this example, I have found a bug ... the VP in the second tree is not packed correctly ... thus the workaround. I will fix the bug in the upcoming version, which, I might announce, has progressed nicely in the past month.)

UPDATE. Answering cfr's comment: `replace by'` (which makes a copy of the replacement subtree) is legit in this example, and almost equivalent to `replace by`. The difference shows only when modifying the nodes, as shown below (or explicitely referring to their `id`.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\Forest*{
  [VP,name=VP
    [V]
    [DP]
  ]
}
\forestset{for name={VP}{for tree={s=0}}}% workaround for the bug
\Forest*{
  copy name template={copy of #1},
  before typesetting nodes={
    for name={VP}{content+=?},
    for name={copy of VP}{content+=!}
  }
  [TP
    [T]
    [,replace by=VP]
    [,replace by'=VP]
  ]
}
\end{document}
```

[image: illustrating <code>replace by'</code>]

Comment: Thank you! I was very confused by this, I'm afraid. In this example, is `replace by` equivalent to `replace by'`. Or should the latter only be used within the scope of a single `forest` environment or command? Good to hear about the progress on the new version!